# Osmand in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, osmand, osmandmapcreator

I try to developed Osmand project in an android studio by using many tutorials 
one of them : 
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/osmand/J0lcnZN0fLU/OT-4gQs_BwAJ
and second :
https://sky4s.blogspot.com/2015/09/android-studioosmand.html

but after i apply all them , i have a build error 
(Java heap space. Please assign more memory to Gradle in the project's gradle.properties file. For example, the following line, in the gradle.properties file, sets the maximum Java heap size to 1,024 MB: *org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m*)

and when i try to solve this problem by increasing the heap size , the android studio take more time to build the project with same problem .
ex:
if heap size was 512 the build take 5 min to show this error ,
if heap size increase to 1024 the build take 9 min to show this error.

Comment: Please be clear when asking the question. It's not clear.

Answer (score 0):

I have built OsmAnd in AS using

*org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4608M*

Comment: This does not sound like an answer, or?